# running kernel 3.x on R Pi 3 Model B?

Tags: pi-3, kernel

I'm looking to run kernel 3.x (3.14 to be exact) on an R Pi 3 Model B hardware. I'm trying to do this by re-compiling the kernel using the instructions here: https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/kernel/building.md

I can successfully recompile and install kernel 4.9. But if I check out kernel branch rpi-3.14.y, I can compile, install, but on boot I get stuck on the 'color pattern' screen.

One thing that is not obvious in this case is that the documentation refers to kernel.img and kernel7.img - and actually both are present on the boot partition. For Model 3 it recommends replacing kernel7.img with the new bzImage. But I could only compile kernel 3.x with the configuration for Model 2 (e.g. bcmrpi_defconfig instead of bcm2709_defconfig)

moreover, when I'm installing modules, I get the following error:

```
  INSTALL sound/usb/snd-usb-audio.ko
  INSTALL sound/usb/snd-usbmidi-lib.ko
  DEPMOD  3.14.28+
depmod: ERROR: Module 'hci_vhci' has devname (vhci) but lacks major and minor information. Ignoring.
```

I wonder how I can make kernel 3.x run on the R Pi 3?

any pointers welcome.

Akos

Comment: That's not the model 2 config, that's a model 1 config.  The last commit to the rpi-3.14-y tree is May 2014, *almost a year before the Pi 2 was released.*  So most likely this is just a no go unless you want to use 3.18+.

Comment: tnx. and how would I go about using 3.18?

Comment: The same way you've been doing what you've been doing already I guess...I just glanced through branches until the first one with a `bcm2709_defconfig`; those are in `arch/arm/configs` (note that conventionally the exact same kernel is used with the Pi 2 and 3).